# SQL: getting rows where some 'x' column value is a maximal one

Tags: sql

I am trying to get data from my database.
Query upon sub-query upon another sub-query - and as the intermediate result I get looks like this:

| item | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| pen | 34 |
| pencil | 42 |
| notebook | 42 |
| eraser | 12 |

I need to build another query upon this result set to get the rows where `item_quantity` has it's maximal value (42 in the example above). The rows with pencils and notebooks. However, I have found out that the task is a bit trickier than I expected it to be.

`SELECT * FROM sub_query_result HAVING quantity = MAX(quantity)`
always returns an empty result set

`SELECT * FROM sub_query_result HAVING quantity = 42`
is pointless since I need to know the exact max quantity in advance

`SELECT * FROM sub_query_result WHERE quantity = MAX(quantity)`
simply works not ("Invalid use of group function")

---

---

I can see solutions that work but that I do not like -- due to extra actions I need to take on my back-end code that executes this sql request, or due to their inefficiency:

- I can create a temporary table, get max. quantity from it and place to a variable. Then I can use this variable inside the query to that temporary table and get the data I need.
- I can do

```
SELECT * FROM query_result HAVING quantity = (SELECT MAX(quantity) FROM 
   <Query upon sub-query upon another sub-query that shall return query_result>)
```

but that way I request the very same data twice! which in general is not a good approach.

---

---

###### So... Anything I missed? Any simple and elegant solutions that can solve my problem?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @SalmanA, how do you know OP is using MySQL?

Comment: Once op tags the rdbms I'll update the duplicate list

Comment: @jarlh it is MariaDB / MySQL but I may need to use this query in another dbms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order by quantity descending to get the max values first. Only select the first row, i.e. the one having the max values. ANSI SQL version:

```
SELECT * FROM query_result
ORDER BY quantity DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES
```

`WITH TIES` means you can get several rows, if there are several rows having the same maximum quantity.

Comment: My outdated MySQL refused to eat this query, but freshly installed MariaDB accepted it and gave me the exact thing I needed.
Thanks a lot!